# Process hanging -SIGALRM not delivered- Perl

Tags: perl

I have a command that I'm executing using OPEN with pipe, and I want to set a timeout of 10 seconds and have the sub process aborted if the execution time exceeds this. However, my code just causes the program to hang- Why is my ALARM not getting delivered properly?

```
my $pid = 0;
my $cmd = "someCommand";
print "Running Command # $num";
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {                    
        print "alarm \n";
        kill 9, $pid;
    };              
    alarm 10;
    pid = open(my $fh, "$cmd|");
    alarm 0;
};
if($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm \n";
} else {
    print $_ while(<$fh>);
}
```

EDIT:

So From the answers below, This is what I have:

```
my $pid = open(my $fh, qq(perl -e 'alarm 10; exec \@ARGV; die "exec: $!\n" ' $cmd |));
print $_ while(<$fh>);
```

But this print ALARM CLOCK to the console when the alarm times out...whereas I dont specify this anywhere in the code...how can I get rid of this, and where would I put the custom alarm event handler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to set a timeout of 10seconds and have the sub process aborted if the execution time exceeds this*

A different approach is to set the alarm on the subprocess itself, with a handy scripting language you already have:

```
my $cmd = "someCommand";
my $pid = open(my $child_stdout, '-|',
   'perl', '-e', 'alarm 10; exec @ARGV; die "exec: $!"', $cmd);
...
```

Your child process will initially be perl (well, the shell and then perl), which will set an alarm on itself and then exec (replace itself with) `$someCommand`.  Pending alarms, however, are [inherited across `exec()`s](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html).

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there anything I can do to reset the alarm for each exec? How would I handle the case that the alarm is raised? As in, where would I put the handling code?

Comment: Thanks, @ikegami.  I resisted that because I suspect "someCommand" might actually be "someCommand --with=blank-separated args".

Comment: @user6561, the alarm _is_ reset for each exec().  It's unique to each spawned process.  Regarding error handling, you'd notice signal death in `$?` after the spawned process terminates.  On my system that's `$? & 127 == 14` (14 is SIGALRM).  See the docs for [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for more detail.

Comment: ok I understand, thanks a lot! 2 more questions: 1. On Perldoc, it says that exec does not return..so in this case, how are we able to put an alarm above exec and wait for it? and 2. When the alarm timesout, does the exec-ed process die?

Comment: @user6561, your perl script will spawn a child.  That child is initially a new perl process.  This second perl process sets an alarm on itself.  It then replaces its process image (`exec()`) with that of your "someCommand".  This new process image is a different program, but retains some attributes of the now-gone second perl process:  PID, parent (that is, we're still a child of your top perl script), process group, session, permissions (usually), *pending kernel alarms*, and more.

Comment: @pilcrow okay..thank you for explaining :) when the alarm timesout, it prints out "ALARM CLOCK" on the command line...is there anyway for me to suppress this?

Comment: @user6561, It's not Perl printing that. If you actually used the code in polcrow's answer, it's coming from your command, and we have no idea what it is, much less how to change its behaviour.

Comment: @ikegami, because I forgot about exec's behavior with a single element array. :)

Comment: @ikegami nope, I dont specify any alarm handler anywhere...ALARM CLOCK that it outputs isnt anywhere in my code...see edit to the original post.

Comment: @user6561, That's not the code in pilcrow's answer. In what you posted, you execute a shell instead of `perl`, and some shells do print that when they receive an alarm signal

Comment: @ikegami can you please explain? It is a .pl file...how am I executing shell instead of perl and what can I do to correct it? I used the command that pilcrow had before u made an edit to avoid shell quoting issue.

Comment: `perl -e 'alarm 10; exec @ARGV; die "exec: $!\n"` is a shell command. You know what's needed to execute a shell command? A shell! so yeah, when you do `open(my $fh, "$shell_command |")`, you are launching a shell. The code in pilcrow's answer executes perl instead of a shell command.

Answer (score 2):

All your code is doing is setting a 10 second timeout on the `open` call, not on the whole external program. You want to bring the rest of your interaction with the external command into the `eval` block:

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {                    
        print "alarm \n";
        kill 9, $pid;
    };              
    alarm 10;
    $pid = open(my $fh, "$cmd|");
    print while <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    alarm 0;
};
if($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm \n";
}
```

Comment: This delivers the ALARM CLOCK signal, but kills the entire program at alarm signal...Might you know why that happens?

Comment: Er, ..., no. Does it execute the `die` function in your `if($@){...}` block? What are the contents of `$@`?